# Помогите правильно настроить nginx

Tags: nginx

Пытаюсь поставить медиа сервер на *ubuntu*, делаю все как [здесь](http://dburianov.pp.ua/?p=14).

но в конце, при выполнении команды

```
sudo /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:1935 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:1935 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:1935 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:1935 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:1935 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

перерыл кучу форумов и статей в гугле, но ничего не помогает.

как это исправить?

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста как правильно

Comment: если знаете поделитесь пожалуйста, буду благодарен, вопрос то все равно остается открытым, сам его решить не могу к сожалению

Comment: а ответ на этот вопрос вы не знаете?

Comment: сделайте пожалуйста, я оплачу, если в этом есть необходимость, токо если можно то подробней именно для этого модуля nginx-rtmp-module

Comment: да ответьте здесь чего кучу вопросов задавать, тем более вопрос задан правильно "Помогите правильно настроить nginx", что тут не в тему?

Comment: а как скоро этого ждать?

Comment: [готово](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/456425/178576). только не забудьте для начала удалить то, что вы устанавливали по упомянутой вами инструкции. для этого перейдите в каталог, где выполняли `sudo make install` и выполните `sudo make uninstall`.

Answer (score 6):

> перерыл кучу форумов и статей в гугле, но ничего не помогает.

потому что достаточно просто перевести фразу

> bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

(привязка к 0.0.0.0:80 завершилась неудачей: адрес уже используется)

У вас что-то (99% что апач) уже висит на восьмидесятом порту и блокирует подъем еще одно сервиса там же. Чтобы nginx стартовал, ему надо либо поменять порт, либо прибить апачелло.

Comment: я это понимаю и запрос в гугле именно такой и делал, порты менял, но выдает туже ошибку, но с другими портами

Answer (score 4):

У Вас nginx стартует на 80 порту,который уже слушает какое то приложение в системе. Попробуйте прибить процесс:

```
sudo fuser -k 80/tcp
```

И перезапустить nginx.

Comment: делал, не помагает

Comment: @Стас покажи результат выполнения 2х команд: ps aufx и netstat -ant | grep -i listen | grep ':80'

Comment: 'stas@stas:/usr/src/nginx-1.7.9$ sudo ps aufx
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    14:18   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    14:18   0:01  \_ [ksoftirqd/
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   14:18   0:00  \_ [kworker/0:
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    14:18   0:18  \_ [rcu_sched]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    14:18   0:00  \_ [rcu_bh]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    14:18   0:00  \_ [migration/'

Comment: это не весь код, там он длинный

Comment: stas@stas:/usr/src/nginx-1.7.9$ sudo netstat -ant | grep -i listen | grep ':80'
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8090            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8091            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN

Comment: netstat явно говорит о том, что 80 порт кто-то слушает. покажи картинкой ps aufx

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй sudo nginx -s stop а затем sudo nginx. Перед этим еще можно sudo srvice nginx stop и затем sudo service nginx start.