# Как правильно собрать пакет с nginx-ом и сторонним модулем?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, debian, dpkg

В отличие от *apache*, модули *nginx*-а компилируются непосредственно в саму программу.

Как **правильно** пересобрать пакет с *nginx*-ом в *debian*-основных дистрибутивах, включив в код программы какой-нибудь сторонний модуль?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

пример для модуля [nginx-rtmp](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module), но подойдёт и для любого другого. только исходники модуля надо будет брать по другой ссылке и распаковывать в каталог с другим именем (не `nginx-rtmp-module`).

1. установим необходимые для сборки пакеты:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update
   $ sudo apt-get install build-essential
   $ sudo apt-get build-dep nginx
   ```
2. создадим где-нибудь в домашнем каталоге «сборочный» каталог и «перейдём» в него:

   ```
   $ mkdir -p ~/sborka/nginx
   $ cd ~/sborka/nginx
   ```
3. скачаем и распакуем исходники дистрибутивного пакета *nginx*:

   ```
   $ apt-get source nginx
   ```
4. помимо нескольких необходимых файлов появился и каталог с исходниками пакета — `nginx-номер.версии`. «перейдём» в него:

   ```
   $ cd nginx-номер.версии
   ```
5. в каталоге `debian/modules` хранятся каталоги с исходниками модулей, которые собираются в одно целое с программой `nginx`. туда и скачаем исходники дополнительного модуля, в каталог (к примеру) `debian/modules/nginx-rtmp-module` (т.к. нам не нужна вся история из репозитория, добавим опцию `--depth 1`):

   ```
   $ git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module.git debian/modules/nginx-rtmp-module
   ```
6. теперь самое «сложное» — надо добавить опцию `--add-module=путь/к/модулю` в «правильном» месте, чтобы она была передана скрипту `configure` при сборке пакета.

   делается это в файле `debian/rules`. это «обыкновенный» `makefile`, но «особого, *debian*-овского назначения». тут два варианта:

   1. в более старых версиях пакета надо использовать переменную `CONFIGURE_OPTS`. если есть её упоминания, то добавьте где-нибудь в начале файла строку:

      ```
      CONFIGURE_OPTS = --add-module=$(MODULESDIR)/nginx-rtmp-module
      ```
   2. в более новых есть переменная `common_configure_flags`. найдите строки вида:

      ```
      common_configure_flags := \
                              --with-cc-opt="$(debian_cflags)" \
                              ...
                              --with-http_realip_module \
      ```

      и после последней добавьте нужную строку, чтобы выглядело примерно так (не забудьте про обратный слэш в конце строки и не удаляйте следующую пустую строку):

      ```
      common_configure_flags := \
                              --with-cc-opt="$(debian_cflags)" \
                              ...
                              --with-http_realip_module \
                              --add-module=$(MODULESDIR)/nginx-rtmp-module \
      ```
7. теперь можно собирать пакет (точнее, их соберётся несколько разных):

   ```
   $ dpkg-buildpackage -b -us -uc
   ```

если последняя команда завершилась успешно (строкой типа `dpkg-buildpackage: binary only upload (no source included)`), то пакеты — собрались.

файлы с ними лежат на каталог выше текущего, т.е. непосредственно в нашем «сборочном» каталоге `~/sborka/nginx`. там присутствуют файлы, включающие в названии буквы `dbg` — это пакеты с отладочной информацией, они обычно не нужны.

нужен как минимум пакет из файла `nginx-common_версия.и.другие.буквы.deb` и один из пакетов, начинающихся с: `nginx-core` (базовая функциональность, «умолчальная» версия) или `nginx-light` («облегчённая» версия) или `nginx-full` («навороченная» версия).

для начала удалите установленную версию `nginx` (если есть):

```
$ sudo apt-get remove 'nginx-*'
```

и поставьте собранные пакеты из файлов:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i ~/sborka/nginx/nginx-common_*.deb ~/sborka/nginx/nginx-core.*.deb
```

если в выводе команды появятся упоминания про неудовлетворённые зависимости, установите их, выполнив:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

теперь можно проверить, присутствует ли упоминание про тот модуль, который вы добавляли (пример был про `rtmp`, эту строку и ищем):

```
$ /usr/sbin/nginx -V |& sed 's/ /\n/g' | grep rtmp
--add-module=/home/.../sborka/nginx/nginx-версия/debian/modules/nginx-rtmp-module
```

*есть такая буква в этом слове!*™