# rtmp модуль nginx

Tags: nginx, debian, apache2, rtmp

Мне надо сделать так, что бы сервер rtsp поток перекодировал в rtmp, который уже можно было б вывести на сайт. Есть инструкция [rtmp модуль nginx](http://sass%20--watch%20css/main.scss:css/main.css%20--style%20compressed)

Сделал все как там, но у меня не заработало. Как можно посмотреть ошибки или понять в чем проблема? Или может кто знает в чем проблема? У меня nginx стоит в связке с apache2, система - Debian 8

Comment: Ссылка не работает

Comment: @KAGGDesign, наверно, эта подразумевалась: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/456425/178576

Comment: извините, вот ссылка - https://www.dmosk.ru/instruktions.php?object=nginx-rtmp