# Как пропатчить showkey?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Возник вопрос, существует задача изменить исходный код утилиты `showkey` в Linux, в режиме `-k`, она имеет особенность выключения после отсутствия ввода с клавиатуры пользователем символов в течении 10 секунд, существует необходимость сделать отключение работы утилиты на клавишу **Enter**, для этого скачали исходники, там существуют библиотеки, которые не являются стандартными, далее перерыв интернет нашёл эти библиотеки на сайте:
https://fossies.org/dox/kbd-2.0.4/getfd_8h_source.html

Исходный код утилиты showkey:
https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/..

После добавления библиотек: `version.h`, `getfd.h`, `nls.h`, `config.h`, `kbd.h`

Была осуществлена попытка компиляции, и были получены следующие ошибки:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. `$ dpkg -S $(which showkey)` 2. [по аналогии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/456425/178576)

Comment: **Была осуществлена попытка компиляции** - каким образом? Вы запускали *configure*? А сборку делали *make*-ом?  Вопросы возникли т.к. (скорее всего) у Вас не нестроен режим сборки.

Answer (score 0):

> Как пропатчить какую-нибудь программу из репозитория debian-основного дистрибутива?

1. надо узнать, в какой пакет входит программа:

   ```
   $ dpkg -S $(which имя-программы)
   ```
2. надо установить исходники и сборочные зависимости пакета.

   1. для начала раскомментируйте записи про исходники пакетов в `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

      ```
      $ sudo sed -i 's/^# deb-src/deb-src/' /etc/apt/sources.list
      ```
   2. обновите список пакетов:

      ```
      $ sudo apt-get update
      ```
   3. установите сборочные зависимости:

      ```
      $ sudo apt-get build-dep имя-пакета
      ```
   4. создайте новый каталог с произвольным именем где-нибудь у себя в домашнем каталоге и сделайте его текущим:

      ```
      $ mkdir ~/build.the.source && cd ~/build.the.source
      ```
   5. скачайте и распакуйте исходники пакета:

      ```
      $ apt-get source имя-пакета
      ```
3. внесите нужные изменения:

   ```
   $ cd ~/build.the.source/имя-пакета-версия-пакета
   $ edit ...
   ```
4. создайте патч:

   ```
   $ dpkg-source --commit
   ```
5. соберите исправленную версию пакета:

   ```
   $ dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
   ```

если сборка прошла успешно, то файл с пакетом находится на один каталог выше — в `~/build.the.source`. распаковать и настроить его можно, как обычно, програмой *dpkg*:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i ~/build.the.source/xyz.deb
```

Comment: Проблема все равно есть: `sudo dpkg -i ~/build.the.source/xyz.deb` после этой команды не видит `gcc` заголовочных файлов, а если писать путь `C_INCLUDE_PATH` такая же ошибка как и раньше

Comment: при чём тут gcc во время установки пакета? вы его собрали? вместо xyz.deb вам надо подставить актуальное имя собранного файла с пакетом.

Comment: выполнил все описанные действия, далее пробуем скомпилировать файл с исходником утилиты showkey.c, компилятор говорит что библиотек нет

Comment: *выполнил все описанные действия* — в пятом пункте происходит **компиляция** программ(ы)/библиотек(и) и упаковка в пакет. ничего компилировать **дополнительно** не надо.