# Как установить nginx redis module на debian 9.5?

Tags: linux, nginx

Пытался скомпилировать nginx redis module для подключения к nginx из репозитория debian 9.5. Но при подключении получаю ошибку module is not binary compatible.

```
    lsb_release -a
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Debian
    Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.5 (stretch)
    Release:    9.5
    Codename:   stretch

    apt-cache show nginx
    Package: nginx
    Version: 1.10.3-1+deb9u1
    Installed-Size: 91
    Maintainer: Debian Nginx Maintainers <pkg-nginx-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
    Architecture: all
    Depends: nginx-full (<< 1.10.3-1+deb9u1.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.10.3-1+deb9u1.1~) | nginx-extras (<< 1.10.3-1+deb9u1.1~), nginx-full (>= 1.10.3-1+deb9u1) | nginx-light (>= 1.10.3-1+deb9u1) | nginx-extras (>= 1.10.3-1+deb9u1)
    Description-en: small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server
     Nginx ("engine X") is a high-performance web and reverse proxy server
     created by Igor Sysoev. It can be used both as a standalone web server
     and as a proxy to reduce the load on back-end HTTP or mail servers.
     .
     This is a dependency package to install either nginx-full (by default),
     nginx-light or nginx-extras.
    Description-md5: 04f6acc7fe672a4d62f4345c9addf4a7
    Homepage: http://nginx.net
    Tag: implemented-in::c, interface::daemon, network::server, network::service,
     protocol::http, role::program, use::proxying
    Section: httpd
    Priority: optional
    Filename: pool/main/n/nginx/nginx_1.10.3-1+deb9u1_all.deb
    Size: 81502
    MD5sum: c95b559748017d27c5d23f42261a4a4b
    SHA256: 951dfb23d22013100af05b9237be5cf35e3eef987c75ca112bc130fa91e65679

    sudo nginx -v
    nginx version: nginx/1.10.3

    wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.10.3.tar.gz
    tar -xzvf nginx-1.10.3.tar.gz
    wget https://people.freebsd.org/~osa/ngx_http_redis-0.3.9.tar.gz
    tar -xzvf ngx_http_redis-0.3.9.tar.gz

    sudo nginx -V
    nginx version: nginx/1.10.3
    built with OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
    TLS SNI support enabled
    configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-2tpxfc/nginx-1.10.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-2tpxfc/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-2tpxfc/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-2tpxfc/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-2tpxfc/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-2tpxfc/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module

    openssl version
    OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017

    sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
    sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev
    sudo apt-get install libgd2-noxpm-dev
    sudo apt-get install libgeoip-dev

    cd nginx-1.10.3/
    ../configure --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-2tpxfc/nginx-1.10.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --add-dynamic-module=../ngx_http_redis-0.3.9
    make modules
    sudo cp objs/ngx_http_redis_module.so /usr/share/nginx/modules/ngx_http_redis_module.so
    sudo cp objs/ngx_http_redis_module.so /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_redis_module.so

    sudo nano /etc/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-redis.conf
    load_module modules/ngx_http_redis_module.so;

    sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-redis.conf /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-redis.conf

    sudo nginx -t
    nginx: [emerg] module "/usr/share/nginx/modules/ngx_http_redis_module.so" is not binary compatible in /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-redis.conf:1
    nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/456425/178576

Comment: начиная с nginx 1.9.x есть поддержка динамических модулей

Comment: какая разница — динамический или нет вы собрали, если он **бинарно несовместим**? вы, видимо, модули для программы linux никогда не собирали.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге собрал модуль с использованием dpkg-buildpackage по мануалу [Как правильно собрать пакет с nginx-ом и сторонним модулем?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/456425/178576) (спасибо за совет alexander-barakin).