# Где находиться configure nginx?

Tags: nginx

Пытаюсь добавить [rtmp](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) модуль, но не могу найти configure файл. Я устанавливал nginx через

`apt-get install nginx`

Где он может находиться?
В файле /etc/nginx его нету
Система Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Он находится в исходных кодах nginx, которые через apt-get install недоступны, потому что apt-get install устанавливает только скомпилированные программы без каких-либо исходных кодов

Comment: @andreymal, А как тогда подключить туда модули? То просит configure для установки

Comment: Вам [сюда](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031953/nginx-rtmp-module-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: а если готовый модуль из пакета (ссылка в предыдущем комментарии) вам по каким-то эзотерическим причинам не подходит, то можете попробовать [собрать его самостоятельно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/456425/178576).