# Слетела кодировка(кракозябры вместо кириллицы)

Tags: кодировка, jupyter-notebook

Спустя какое-то время слетела кодировка с проектов, которые загружал на github. Работал в Jupyter Notebook. Собственно, как это выглядит[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подскажите, можно ли как то решить проблему?

Comment: @SpaceResearcher не стоит повторять название метки в заголовке вопроса.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin,вероятно стоит, чтобы участники конкретно понимали вопрос, вот пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/456425/441356
Изначально в метках не стоял юпитер, его добавил я, но тем не менее, никто не пойдет по заголовку и метке где именно слетела кодировка. Она могла слететь при записи в файл с помощью юпитера или при сохранении файлов(блокнотов) самого юпитера и после открытия вместо кириллических комментов были бы непонятные символы.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin более того метки существуют не для описания вопроса или его заголовка, а для быстрого поиска интересующих тем, так что я склоняюсь к тому, что написать конкретный вопрос это то, что нужно.

Comment: @SpaceResearcher, почитайте, пожалуйста, сопутствующие обсуждения на мете: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%5D+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5+is%3Aq и лучше обсуждать мета-вопросы там же, на мете.